# Plugin for color blindness?

Tags: color, software-recommendation, mac, accessibility

Is there a plugin for any of the Adobe apps or in general that adjust on-screen colors for custom color blindness deficiencies?

This way the affected designer can design seeing the colors clearly and the output would be accurate or correct for normal users and/or printers.

Ultimately, having something on the MacOS level would be the best thing and this way you wouldn't have to on a per-app basis.

Comment: I don't quite understand this request. If the designer has, for instance, [Deuteranopia](https://www.color-blindness.com/deuteranopia-red-green-color-blindness/), no amount of red/green exaggeration is going to make them capable of differentiating red from green.

Comment: Aren't there glasses for red-green colour blindness?  I'm sure I've seen them demonstrated on youtube. Ask your optician about them. I suppose it would depend on what kind of colour blindness you have.

Comment: @Tetsujin  My thought behind the questions is the ability to adjust color levels to accurately reflect (to the designer) the correct color. Perhaps, there is a test/calibration visually that the designer goes through before using the plugin. I know they have that kind of thing for sound. They go through a test/calibration so that certain frequencies are adjusted for the best possible listening experience. I figured, why not for color blindness. Perhaps I'm looking at in too simplistic terms but never hurts to ask.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, they do. The one I'm aware of is called "EnChroma". But not sure if that is the best solution. I personally havent' used them so can't vouch for them.

Comment: Found this about the EnChroma glasses.  https://phys.org/news/2018-10-scientists-debunk-effectiveness-enchroma-glasses.html

Comment: I found this link for software that claims to be able to filter colours on a computer for colour blind users https://www.ryobi-sol.co.jp/visolve/en/visolve.html - I have no idea if it works and can't test, since I'm not colour blind. Good luck!

Comment: @BillyKerr - looks like the intent of the linked software is to filter the images in such a way as to ease discrimination of colours which a colourblind viewer might have trouble telling apart - it doesn't claim to try to correct for colourblindness it the literal sense that OP has asked for - AFAIK, that isn't possible. I've a colourblind parent, so have kept awareness of these issues lifelong.

Comment: This could be done by crafting a color profile.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way where you can preview the design and see how it would look to a person with color blindness. There is an automatic way built inside the Adobe Illustrator CC 2020 (ver 24.0.2). Go to `View` > `Proof Setup` [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to check this.

- [Sim Daltonism](https://michelf.ca/projects/sim-daltonism/)
- [Coblis](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/)
- Illustrator and Photoshop (View > Proof Setup > Color Blindness > Protanopia or Color Blindness > Deuteranopia)
- [Chromatic Vision Simulator](https://asada.website/cvsimulator/e/)
- [Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/)
- Several browser plugins

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way. And this is probably due color is a subjective thing. 
You probably are facing specific challenges that need to be solved by different means.

Some options:

- Prepare custom pallets, that you know that work in general.
- Study in depth color theory, especially chromatic contrast, harmony, etc.
- Convert from time to time your files to black and white. To see how they work, then add the color theory on top.
- Submit a preview to some college for a quick review, take notes and adjust your palettes accordingly.

---

I insist that programs like Photoshop try to add unnecessary tools, instead of adding some other useful ones.

One tool they lack is a vectorscope. In video, it is used to find the coordinates of the skin tones for example.

Take a look at this specific case: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59595/how-can-i-correctly-adjust-skin-color-in-photoshop-when-i-have-a-color-vision-de/82987#82987

Comment: SUPER delayed response but Life. ;)  Thank you for the thoughtful answer. I'll look into it.